# Play framework 2.2.x: Image upload in Java

Tags: java, image, file-upload, playframework

I am new to Play Framework. I am using Play framework v2.2.6 for my REST-full backend application. I want to provide a REST api for file upload, especially image file. I am developing my application in Java.

I searched a lot but I didn't get any sample example in Java. Anyone have done anything similar?

This is what I would like to do:

1. Provide a route to upload image file.
2. In the controller, I would like to check if its an image file or not. If not then return bad request.
3. If its an image file, then save it in the file system on the server and save the location to that file.
4. Provide a route to retrieve the saved file.

Answer (score 2):

A few days ago I wrote a minimal sample application for uploading files and store them as BLOB in your database: [Github](https://github.com/DirtyDan88/play-framework-blob) Maybe it's useful for you...

Comment: So you are saving the uploaded image in the in-memory database. right? How do I modify it to save the image in the file system instead of DB and retrieve from file system?

Comment: Instead of writing the file in an byte array (in Image-class) you can say: image.renameTo(new File("public/images/", name)); to save it to your filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

The html input control

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">
```

The Javascript function

```
function myFunction(){
var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
var txt = "";
var src="";
if ('files' in x) {
    if (x.files.length == 0) {
        txt = "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
            txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
            var file = x.files[i];



            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('picture', file);
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/upload',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });


            if ('name' in file) {
                txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
            }
            if ('size' in file) {
                txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
            }
        }
    }
} 
else {
    if (x.value == "") {
        txt += "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
        txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
        txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value; // If the browser does not support the files property, it will return the path of the selected file instead. 
    }
}
```

console.log(txt);
}

The route

```
POST    /upload                         controllers.Application.upload
```

The controller

```
public static Result upload() {
      MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
      FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");
      if (picture != null) {
        String fileName = picture.getFilename();
        String contentType = picture.getContentType(); 
        File file = picture.getFile();
        return ok("File uploaded");
      } else {
        flash("error", "Missing file");
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Its copy paste from documentation, how I get bytes to store that!

Comment: @Al-Mothafar You can do that as   InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(file); byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; then you can write that with OutputStream  as int length;
     
     while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

      outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

     }